# loop not working,<function numz at 0x7fa66078bbf8>

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

```
import random
Grades = ["A*", "A", "B", "C", "D", "U"]
def numz():
    for x in range(0,20):
        print(x)

counter = 0
a = True
while a is True:
    print("candidate" ,numz, ":" , random.choice(Grades) , random.choice(Grades) , random.choice(Grades))
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter == 20:
        a = False
```

the print is
candidate <function numz at 0x7fa66078bbf8> : A* B D
candidate <function numz at 0x7fa66078bbf8> : B U U

Comment: Why do you have `numz` in the `print`? `numz` needs to be called (`numz()`), and also, it doesn't return anything; it prints values instead. What's your intent there?

Comment: I think you meant `print("candidate", counter)` because `numz` is a function.

Comment: Your code could also be cleaner, but I don't get the point of the `numz` function if I understand what you're trying to do correctly.

Answer (score 1):

the function needs to be called : `nums()`

Answer (score 0):

Your question might be better addressed if you include a description of what you expected it to do?

if you add () to numz it will at least call the function.

```
print("candidate" ,numz(), ":" , random.choice(Grades) , random.choice(Grades) , random.choice(Grades))
```